# Apache Solr still keep old data after delta import

Tags: solr, lucene, dataimporthandler

I am using solr 7.6.

I do full import from mysql, the table `customer` looks like:

```
customer_id pk   int
customer_code    varchar
name             varchar
update_datetime  timestamp
```

I modify one record, change

```
customer_id    customer_code    name

46027          C1               zxc
```

to

```
customer_id    customer_code    name

46027          C1               789
```

then I do delta import with `data-config` looks like

```
<dataConfig>

  <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" user="test" password="123456"/>
  <document>

    <entity name="customer" pk="customer_id"
            query="select customer_id, customer_code, name from customer"
            deltaImportQuery="select customer_id, customer_code, name from customer where customer_id='${dih.delta.customer_id}'"
            deltaQuery="select customer_id from customer where update_datetime &gt; '${dih.last_index_time}'"
            >        
    </entity>
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

delta import is success, solr can return the new result with query `name:789`.

However, when I query with old data `name:zxc`, it still can return old data:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"name",
      "_":"1547619027918"}},
  "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "customer_id":46027,
        "name":"zxc",
        "id":"dd513a36-dfff-4ed2-a4fe-f728f42adfce",
        "_version_":1622797739301535744}]
  }}
```

Why? and how can I make solr delete the old data if this record has been updated?

`customer_id` is the primary key whose type is `int` in MySql.

I added `customer_id` and `name` to `schema` of Solr and set `customer_id` as `pint`.

Next screenshot is the `schema` tag of Solr, it says the `unique key field` is `id`.

[image]

---------------- **UPDATE** -------------------

the `managed-schema.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Solr managed schema - automatically generated - DO NOT EDIT -->
<schema name="default-config" version="1.6">
  <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
  <fieldType name="ancestor_path" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.PathHierarchyTokenizerFactory" delimiter="/"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="binary" class="solr.BinaryField"/>
  <fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true"/>
  <fieldType name="booleans" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true" multiValued="true"/>

  <!-- field : delimited_payloads_float, delimited_payloads_int, 
  delimited_payloads_string, descendent_path, location, location_rpt,
   lowercase-->

  <!-- field starts with p, e.g. pdate -->

  <fieldType name="random" class="solr.RandomSortField" indexed="true"/>
  <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" docValues="true"/>
  <fieldType name="strings" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" docValues="true" multiValued="true"/>

  <!-- field name starts with text_-->

  <field name="customer_id" type="pint" uninvertible="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="name" type="text_en" uninvertible="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="_root_" type="string" docValues="false" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
  <field name="_text_" type="text_general" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
  <field name="_version_" type="plong" indexed="false" stored="false"/>
  <field name="id" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true"/>

  <!-- default dynamic fields -->
</schema>
```

Comment: Whats the unique id for the solr document?

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti I updated it, please see the `update` part of bottom

Comment: Is the field named "id" is same as "customer_id". Have you created any alias for it.Could you please share the field Definition from schema.xml?

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti the field `id` is default, I didn't create any alias for it. Please see the `managed-schema.xml` at the bootom.

Comment: Please follow the answer provided by MatsLindh

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti Got it, thank you for your tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't have a value for the id field, Solr is generating a unique one for you. You'll have to either include an id that is actually the unique id for the document you're submitting, or change the uniqueKey definition - I suggest doing the first, as it can then easily be changed later if necessary.

If `customer_id` uniquely identifies the document, add `customer_id AS id, ..` to your SQL SELECT statements:

```
SELECT customer_id AS id, customer_id, customer_code, name FROM customer
```

Comment: I added `customer_id as id` to `query` and `deltaImportQuery`, it works, thanks! But I found that the response only has `id`, `name` and `_version_`, the `customer_id` disappear.  Could I take `customer_id` as `uniqueKey` and remove the filed `id`? I tried take `customer_id` as `uniqueKey` in `managed-schema.xml` manually, but this result in my core cannot start.

Comment: In my example `customer_id` is mentioned twice - if you only changed it to `AS id`, there will be only one column returned under the name `id`. Add `, customer_id` as well, so you get the value twice - once under the customer_id field and once under the id field. You can also add a `copyField` instruction to your schema to do this on the Solr side.

Comment: Got it! So could I use `customer_id` as `uniqueKey` directly and remove field `id`?

Comment: It's an option, but that will probably also require removing the update processor that adds the GUID when indexing.